# Get specific node id from the figure plot by osmnx

Tags: python, plot, openstreetmap, networkx

Now I can plot the map using osmnx, but I don't know the node id of nodes in the figure. That is how can I associate the node id and the node plot in the figure? Or, Can I plot the map with node id? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `annotate` parameter to `True` in the osmnx.plot.plot_graph() module.

Comment: Is there a way to selectively annotate nodes that fit some condition? If you have a large graph, annotating gets very messy..

Comment: I cannot find the annotate parameter in the current docs
https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph